# How to get inline xml schema?

Tags: c#, xml

this is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <xs:schema xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" id="NewDataSet">
    <xs:element msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true" name="NewDataSet">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:element name="Table1">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" msdata:DateTimeMode="Unspecified" name="MAXTIME" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="X" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Y" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Z" type="xs:string"/>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <Table1>
    <MAXTIME/>
    <X>123</X>
    <Y>DDo</Y>
    <Z>Cri</Z>
  </Table1>
</NewDataSet>
```

I want to get the xml schema from the above xml file, however when I use

```
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlPath);
        XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
        XmlSchemaInference schema = new XmlSchemaInference();
        schemaSet = schema.InferSchema(reader);
```

it fails:

```
The supplied xml instance is a schema or contains an inline schema. This class cannot infer a schema for a schema.
```

so how should I get it to get the schema

Comment: What's the failure message?

Comment: @TanveerBadar: The supplied xml instance is a schema or contains an inline schema. This class cannot infer a schema for a schema.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
DataSet dset = new DataSet();
dset.ReadXml("xmlFile.xml",XmlReadMode.IgnoreSchema);
var _schema = dset.GetXmlSchema();
```

Comment: not work, how can get schema when you have ignore it ?

Comment: @jimboR The ignore means ignore get existing schema